# SSRS Tablix control with Dynamic row height

Tags: dynamic, ssrs-2008, row, ssrs-tablix, row-height

I am trying to show the tablix rows in multiple pages and some pages I want to display 80 rows some other pages just go with 32 rows and this value is configured from the backend and it is a part of the dataset. How will I enforce tablix to take the row height value from the dataset?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly change the height of the text box.However you can change the padding on top and bottom based on number of rows in  your dataset.
Try finding some ballpark figure with the number of rows that you have and the padding that you want to add.Lesser the rows more the padding.To achieve this

Go to ->Any Text Box in  Tablix ->In the Top and bottom padding  ->Click the on dropdown arrow ->Click on Expression .... -> In Expression

```
             =IIF(First("RowCount","DataSet1").Value < 50 ,10,5)
```

You can also come up with a factor say once you understand how the padding should be affected by number of rows.

```
            =(1 - First("RowCount","DataSet1").Value)/32 * 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did this by adding another element to the page group ie page number and derived page number in the backend. When row is auto size rows would be expanded or reduced the height.

Comment: thats another good solution , so you are setting the conditional page break on that group?